# regarding odd perfect numbers

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

$$3-1=2$$
Let $n$ be a perfect number. Subtract each proper divisor from greatest to least. Example: $n=28$

28-14=14. 14-7=7. 7-4=3. 3-**2**=1. 1-1=**0**

With an even perfect number, we can go from $n$ down to one half of $n$ with one move. With an odd perfect number, the first move, at best, only gets us as far down as two thirds of $n$. $n-n/3=2n/3$

Keep subtracting until there is nothing left. With an even perfect number, eventually we get down to 3 and then subtract 2. $3-2=1$ Finally, we subtract 1 to get to **0**. $1-1=0$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you arguing that the sum of the divisors of an odd number must be less than the number?  This is false...$945$ being the smallest counterexample (I think).

Comment: I am experiencing technical difficulties. Some things are not displaying properly on my screen.

Comment: But, are you claiming that, for odd $n$, the sum of the proper divisors of $n$ is less than $n$?  As I say, that claim is false for $945$ (the proper divisors add to $975$).

Comment: Let me check. If so then I should have said greater than.

Comment: "With an even perfect number, eventually we get down to 3"  Why? 3 isn't nesc a factor.  3 is not a factor of 28. "Finally, we subtract 1 to get to 0. 1−1=0" Why do we subtract 1?  1 isn't the next divisor less than 1.  So if we get to 3 with an odd the next step is 3-1 = 2.  And ... 2-1 = 0.   If you got 3 in 28 when 3 doesn't divide 28 we can get to 2 when 2 doesn't divide n.

Comment: The "hand-waving" step is the following: "*At best, we could get down to $3$*." You haven't justified this at all, and as @lulu's counterexample shows, you won't be able to.

Comment: @fleablood: No, $3$ isn't necessarily a factor of an even perfect number, but $1$ and $2$ *are*, and $1+2=3.$ Remember that the algorithm suggested is subtracting all proper divisors from greatest to least.

Comment: Shouldn't 28 go:  28-14=14; 14-7=7; 7-4=3;4-2=2;2-1=1.  And that's the end of it?  We shouldn't ever have 3-2 because 3 isn't a factor.  What exactly is this exerise supposed to show?  We does n have to be perfect?

Comment: @fleablood: $7-4=3,$ $3-2=1,$ $1-1=0.$

Comment: @CameronBuie ????????  what is the purpose of all this.  So what if 1 + 2 = 3?  What is the question in the first place?

Comment: Ok. 945 is (3^3)(5)(7). I will need some time to check this counter example.

Comment: @fleablood: The OP is attempting to prove that no odd perfect number exists. The algorithm they are using to check is successively subtracting all of the proper divisors of  the number, from greastest to least. For example, $6-3=3,$ $3-2=1,$ $1-1=0.$ Since the result of the algorithm is $0$, then $6$ is perfect.

Comment: "With an odd perfect number, the first move, at best, only gets us as far down as two thirds of n"  Why should that matter?  That only means that the rest of the factors must add to 2/3 n or greater.  No reason that can't happen.

Comment: @fleablood: By contrast, the algorithm yields $1$ when applied to $8,$ and yields $-12$ when applied to $30,$ so neither of these is perfect.

Comment: I see that now.  It wasn't clear what the OPs rationale was.  The way to was presented I thought s/he was subtracting the factors from each other.

Comment: @lulu, you are correct, $945$ is the first odd abundant number.  See https://oeis.org/A005231 for more.

Comment: @CameronBuie 8=>1 and 30=>-12.  So 8 is "less than perfect" and 30 is "more than perfect".  This demonstrates that factors can add up to more or to less than n/2.  So the objection that the first subtract only goes to 2/3 isn't nesc. relevent.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Thanks...I wrote a quick routine to get that, but I didn't fully trust it.

Comment: Having read about abundant numbers - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number - I say that an odd abundant number is not perfect. So 945 is not perfect, but I will have give thought to odd abundant numbers.

Comment: @fleablood: I completely agree that said objection has no relevance. I must admit, I had to infer heavily from the original title and the fact that the OP expected $0$ as the algorithm's result. Otherwise, I wouldn't have had any idea what was going on, here.

Comment: @Jeffrey: *No* abundant number is perfect. Every positive integer is exactly one of the following: deficient, perfect, abundant.

Comment: The point of 945 being abundant is not that 945 might be perfect.  (It can't; abundant and perfect are contradictory).  The point is that 945 despite being odd and only reaching 2/3 n = 945 - 315 = 630 on it's first step, does indeed get *below* 2 so the objection never gets to 2 is invalid.  945 - 315 = 630; 630 - 189= 441; 441 -135 = 306; 306-105=201;201-63=138; 138 - 45 =93; 93 - 45 = 48; 48-35=13; 13-27 = -14... so we have gotten quite a bit past 3.  It's not that we haven't gone far enough; we've gone *way* too far.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the terms "dificient" and "abundant".  But the OP argument seems to be "odd numbers must be deficient as each step must reduce by less than 1/2" .  But that'd only hold if there were at most $\log_2 n$ factors of n.  As there may be many factors they can add up to more than 1/2 the sum even if no individual one does.

Comment: @lulu: The counter example of 945 is good. There is a point in the algorithm where 16-15=1. If then we only had 1 left to subtract, we would have an odd perfect number.

Comment: Having removed that which was proven false, there is little left of my question. So the question was answered definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An odd perfect number has an odd number of positive divisors less than the number itself.

This happens since the number of all the positive divisors of a number $n$ (including $n$) is odd only if $n$ is a perfect square and we know that this is not possible for odd perfect numbers.

So $n$ has an even number of divisors which gives an odd number of divisors without $n$ itself.

Note that odd-odd=even and that even-odd=odd.

The last step will be to subtract an odd divisor from an odd number which is possible to give the answer $0$ so there is no problem actually.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the factors do not result in factors.

28-14=14; 14-7 = 7; 7 - 4 = 3

But $3 \not \mid 28$.

So for and odd $n$ you will get:

$n- f_1 = n_2;......; n_k - smallestOddFactorGreaterThan1 = 2; 2 - 1 = 1$.

There's utterly no reason on earth to assume $n_k - smallestOddFactorGreaterThan1 = 2$ isn't possible.  In fact, half the running totals will be even.